# Why is my IsBiggerThanHalf stuck in in infinite loop?

Tags: assembly, avr

When I run this code through the debugger I noticed that after I push mpr in the function it gets a value of 0x10 and that it infinitely loops, never triggering the sbrs instruction. Why is this happening?

```
.include "m128def.inc"          ; Include definition file

;***********************************************************
;*  Internal Register Definitions and Constants
;***********************************************************
.def    mpr = r22               ; Multipurpose register is


;***********************************************************
;*  Start of Code Segment
;***********************************************************
.cseg                           ; Beginning of code segment

;***********************************************************
;*  Interrupt Vectors
;***********************************************************
.org    $0000                   ; Beginning of IVs
        rjmp INIT               ; Reset interrupt

.org    $0046                   ; End of Interrupt Vectors

;***********************************************************
;*  Program Initialization
;***********************************************************
INIT:                           ; The initialization routine
        ldi     mpr, low(RAMEND)
        out     SPL, mpr        ; Load SPL with low byte of RAMEND
        ldi     mpr, high(RAMEND)
        out     SPH, mpr        ; Load SPH with high byte of RAMEND


;***********************************************************
;*  Main Program
;***********************************************************
MAIN:   
        rcall IsBiggerThanHalf
        rjmp    MAIN            

IsBiggerThanHalf:                           
        push    mpr
        inc     mpr
        sbrs    mpr, 7
        rjmp    IsBiggerThanHalf
        pop     mpr
        ret
```

Comment: Seems strange to me, but I don't know AVR very well.  However, you should be able to make the loop more efficient: instead of conditionally skipping the `rjmp`, do `inc r22` / `brpl IsBiggerThanHalf` to keep looping while the INC result is non-negative.  INC already sets flags according to the result, including the N flag according to the MSB.

Comment: Note that you `push` n times (inside the loop) but only `pop` once.  So `ret` will pop some previously-pushed value, not the return address.  At least it would if execution ever got out of your loop, which you're saying doesn't happen.  Make sure you're using your debugger correctly to actually verify that, not depending on any other assumptions like that you'll return to the `rjmp` in `MAIN`.